# Magit: Copy text from Stage section without character "+"

Tags: magit

<sup>Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Magit</sup>

I select some text (Shift + Arrow Down) from the **Unstaged changes** section.
Here is a screenshot:

[image: Select_text]

Then I paste into another buffer (`*scratch*`).

This is the result:

[image: Result_paste]

Is it possible to strip the leading `+`s when killing lines from diff hunks?

Answer (score 8):

Magit doesn't support that currently, but it should be doable. I'll probably do that soon. I sometimes could use that feature too.

Meanwhile use a macro to replace the `+`s after yanking: `<f3> C-d C-n <f4>...`.

Comment: After yank I do next: 1) Set cursor over first "+", 2) Start command `<C-return>` (`cua-set-rectangle-mark`) , 3) Select only "+" (one column) and press **Del** for delete all symbols "+"

Comment: @Alex Could you not use `cua-rectangle-mark-mode` from within the magit buffer?

Comment: I use `cua-rectangle-mark-mode` in another buffer (not magit) after yank text.

Comment: Without CUA, after yank: `C-a` `C-f` `C-x C-x` `C-x r d`.

Answer (score 4):

Until Magit supports something like this, the behavior is easy to get
with a custom command.  I have something similar to the following
command in my configuration.  If you call it with a prefix argument,
it will remove the leading diff markers.

```
(defun km/magit-copy-region-hunk (&optional no-column)
  (interactive "P")
  (when (magit-section-internal-region-p)
    (magit-section-when hunk
      (deactivate-mark)
      (let ((text (buffer-substring-no-properties
                   (region-beginning) (region-end))))
        (kill-new (if no-column
                      (replace-regexp-in-string "^[ \\+\\-]" "" text)
                    text))))))
```

---

*Edit*: With the developmental version of Magit (what will be v2.91.0), you can strip the diff markers by marking a region of a hunk and calling `magit-copy-section-value` with a prefix argument.

Comment: No docstrings in your configuration?! For shame. :) Works well though +1.

Answer (score 3):

Going off of Kyle Meyer's answer, if you want to copy the diff without needing to hit the prefix key, you can use the following:

```
(defun copy-diff-region ()
  "Copy diff region without + or - markers."
  (interactive)
  (deactivate-mark)
  (let ((text (buffer-substring-no-properties
               (region-beginning) (region-end))))
    (kill-new (replace-regexp-in-string "^[\\+\\-]" "" text))))
```